# Adding front-end frameworks to GWT

Tags: java, gwt, zurb-foundation

I normally do my web development in java using wicket or php building my UI using zurb foundation. Recently though I was asked to do some development using GWT. I am coming up to speed but am wondering if there is a way to add in a front-end framework like foundation. I found a bootstrap implementation [here](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/) and am wondering if creating such a wrapper is the only way to do something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a @JsInterop in GWT 2.8.0 - Something that should ease the integration between native JavaScript frameworks and GWT. If you want to import a widget library yourself - this should be the way.

Also you can just access your JS-widget through JSNI (but having lots of js code kills the idea of using GWT if you ask me)

Another way - Use existing GWT frameworks: [Sencha GXT](https://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/), [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) and maybe [SmartGWT](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/) Also check the jQuery~ish library for GWT if you like your selectors https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtquery

Comment: I think what I am looking for is more the ability to build my UI more like I am used to with HTML5 and CSS3. It looks like it is more xml and panels in gwt. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Web components could do it for you. You'll create HTML+CSS components, wire them through html imports, throw some @JsInterop here and there - give polymer framework a look

Comment: Here's an example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit?pref=2&pli=1#

Comment: Give a try: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/ , see code section to have an idea of how easy to code in smartclient gwt, but you will need web service and backend side. Other posibility will be Vaadin because it is already backend/frontend

Comment: You should check this also: https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/ I use it and love it.